# require is not defined at lodash.js:1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, lodash

I need to use lodash to process some of the data at the client side. Lodash seems to be perfect, however after I installed it via
`npm install lodash`and included it with

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/lodash/chain/lodash.js"></script>
```

I'm getting an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at lodash.js:1
```

I know the browser side doesn't support module loading using `require`, but how else am I supposed to use lodash there?

PS. It's the `_.find()` I need.

Comment: By using any webpacker, for instance, you can include it.

Comment: Use the lodash from its CDN? And if you are only looking at the _.find() function you might prefer using a custom build as to not include unecessary code. All is explained on the lodash website.

Comment: did you try using [browserify](http://browserify.org/)?